# Pixelation in VideoView in Android ONLY with Wifi connection (3G/4G runs perfectly)

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-wifi, rtsp

I have a problem that, after googling, I don't know why it is happenning.

I 've made and streaming video app with protocol RTSP. All is working good with a 3G/4G connection, but if i change to Wifi, much times video appears with a pixelation like a grey screen.

Testing in Android 5.1 (LG G3). 
minSDKVersion = 15.
compiledSDKVersion = 22.

[image]

If i change to 3g, all goes well. It seems a problem of the initial buffer but its weird, because the problem is with Wifi connection (tested with two different connections, one xVDSL and one FTTH).

I'm not using any library, doing all the work directly with the android sdk and VideoView and mediaPlayer.

Here the code that init the configuration and how it handle the listeners:

```
videoView= (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(null);
videoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL));
```

start/stop methods (the button above) and override listener methods:

```
public void startVideo(){
    if(videoView !=null) {
        initProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.load_streaming));
        startProgressDialog();
        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        //btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }
}

public void stopVideo(){
    if(videoView !=null) {
        btnPlay.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.video_button_play));
        stateVideo=2;
        videoView.suspend();


    }
}

public void resumeVideo(){
    if(videoView !=null) {
        initProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.load_streaming));
        startProgressDialog();
        btnPlay.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.video_button_stop));
        stateVideo=1;
        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoView.resume();



    }
}

private boolean manageErrorVideo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1){



    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    stopProgressDialog();
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    //A lot of control error code. If need, ask but never go this way when the problem appear.
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    btnPlay.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.video_button_stop));
    videoView.start();
    stopProgressDialog();
    stateVideo = 1;
    findViewById(R.id.mainView).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    Log.d("test", mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight() + "");
    Log.d("test", mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth()+"");
}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

}
```

Any information or help will be wellcome!

Thank you!!

EDIT: RTSP server is an IP camera.

Comment: Firstly I think you are testing on a device itself - testing video in the emulator is not reliable unfortunately? Assuming this is the case the problem you describe sounds like it could also be due to the WiFi network itself - have you been able to test on multiple WiFi networks?

Comment: @Mick Cannot test the video in emulator... I've tried with two diferent Wifi's in diferent buildings and different operators (movistar and Vodafone)and it still happens...

Comment: You are streaming from a server to the phone, correct? Are you able to share the URL of the video being streamed?